# Color merge from RGB specification

Tags: color

With the `xcolor` package one can define colors in many ways for example, using standard names,

`\colorbox{red}{...}`

Merging colors

`\colorbox{red!25}{...}`

`\colorbox{red!25!blue}{...}`

Or from the RGB or CYMK values

`\colorbox[rgb]{0.1,0.2,0.3}{...}`

Is it possible to combine *inline* the RGB and merging approaches? For example

`\colorbox[rgb]{0.1,0.2,0.3 ! 25}{...} %invalid code`

`\colorbox{\color[rgb]{0.70,0.05,0.65}!25}{...} %also invalid`

To make a given RGB color lighter. The context is that for a given element I know the RGB value but I want to make it lighter by merging with white.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox[rgb]{0.70,0.05,0.65}{A} % this turns to be dark violet, how to get something like {violet!25}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can do it. The [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package offers a very sofisticated  extended syntax for mixing colors (refer to pages 14-16 of the `xcolor` documentation for details):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{rgb:red,0.70;green,0.05;blue,0.65}{A} % this turns to be dark violet, how to 

\colorbox{rgb:red!40,0.70;green!40,0.05;blue!40,0.65}{A}

\colorbox{rgb:red!10,0.70;green!10,0.05;blue!10,0.65}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more "in-line" shades:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\colorbox{rgb:red,0.70;green,0.05;blue,0.65}{A}\quad % this turns to be dark violet, how to 
\foreach \Valor in {90,80,...,10}
{%
  \colorbox{rgb:red!\Valor,0.70;green!\Valor,0.05;blue!\Valor,0.65}{A}\quad
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, you can produce many variations using this method and, more complexes mixes or, for example, the complement operator `-`. A little example showing "in-line" variations of your initial color:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{rgb:red,0.70;green,0.05;blue,0.65}{A} % this turns to be dark violet, how to 

\colorbox{rgb:red!40,0.70;green!40,0.05;blue!40,0.65}{A}

\colorbox{rgb:red!10,0.70;green!10,0.05;blue!10,0.65}{A}

\colorbox{rgb:red!10!cyan,0.70;green!60!cyan,0.05;blue!10,0.65}{A}

\colorbox{rgb:-red!10!cyan,0.70;green!60!cyan,0.05;blue!10,0.65}{A}

\colorbox{rgb:red!10!cyan,0.70;-green!60!cyan,0.05;blue!10!orange,0.65}{A}

\colorbox{rgb:-red!10!cyan,0.70;-green!60!cyan,0.05;blue!10!orange,0.65}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. Do you know what is the logic behind the `rgb:` if after that one can put any color names?

Comment: @alfC `rgb` selects the color model; the color represented by `red` for example depends on the chosen model. Compare these two (the only difference is the model): `\colorbox{rgb:red,0.70;green,0.05;blue,0.65}{A}
\colorbox{cmyk:red,0.70;green,0.05;blue,0.65}{A}`

Answer (score 4):

Typically this is done by defining the colour *first*, after which you can shade (or merge it):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.70,0.05,0.65}
\begin{document}
\colorbox[rgb]{0.70,0.05,0.65}{A} % this turns to be dark violet, how to get something like {violet!25}

\colorbox{violet}{A}

\colorbox{violet!25}{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is most likely possible to define colours based on what you supply. However, then one would have to compete with the syntax of merged/mixed colours: `colour1!<num>!colour2!<num>!colour3!<num>!colour4!...`

Comment: So, no chance to have it inline? I have to color many elements with unique colors and it seems a waste to define a color that will be used only once.

Comment: I never was able to "merge" more than two colors, for example `red!70!green!5!blue!65` produces a mostly pure blue. Otherwise you are right, I could add something at the end, like `!white`.

Comment: @alfC: You can use `\definecolor` even on an existing colour. So, you don't have to create a new colour each time. Create the colours for the display and re-use the name.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a wrapper command e.g. `\rgbbox[<optional proportion>]{<rgb specification>}{<contents>}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\rgbbox[3][100]{%
  \definecolor{rgbboxcolour}{rgb}{#2}%
  \colorbox{rgbboxcolour!#1}{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
\colorbox[rgb]{0.70,0.05,0.65}{A} % this turns to be dark violet, how to get something like {violet!25}

\rgbbox[25]{0.70,0.05,0.65}{B}

\rgbbox[50]{.25,.75,.75}{C}

\rgbbox{.25,.75,.75}{D}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Note that if the optional argument is not specified, you get no mixing i.e. 100% of the colour given in the first mandatory argument.